# Karma/Jasmine Unit Test of Component with Injected Service in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, adal

I am new to Karma/Jasmine unit testing, and I am attempting to write some tests for my authentication component that has an AuthService injected into it.  I also have another authentication service that is used for Microsoft (Azure) authentication injected into the general AuthService.  For building my spec, I have:

```
describe('AuthAdminComponent', function () {
  let de: DebugElement;
  let comp: AuthAdminComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AuthAdminComponent>;
  let authService: AuthService;

  let authServiceStub: {
    // Fill in later
  }

    beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AuthAdminComponent ], // declare the test component
      providers: [
        {provide: AuthService, useValue: authServiceStub},
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents(); // compile template and css
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AuthAdminComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    authService = TestBed.get(authService) // Get the needed service
  });

})
```

There are not any tests currently because I wanted to make sure everything is getting set up correctly.  However, when I run `npm test`, I receive:

```
404: /base/node_modules/ng2-adal/core.js
Chrome 59.0.3071 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR

{
[1]     "originalErr": {
[1]       "__zone_symbol__currentTask": {
[1]         "type": "microTask",
[1]         "state": "notScheduled",
[1]         "source": "Promise.then",
[1]         "zone": "<root>",
[1]         "cancelFn": null,
[1]         "runCount": 0
[1]       }
[1]     },
[1]     "__zone_symbol__currentTask": {
[1]       "type": "microTask",
[1]       "state": "notScheduled",
[1]       "source": "Promise.then",
[1]       "zone": "<root>",
[1]       "cancelFn": null,
[1]       "runCount": 0
[1]     }
[1]   }
```

I don't particularly understand where I've gone wrong.  Apparently, it's not finding that .js file, but that .js file does exist in that location and works fine when I run the Angular app normally.  So I just assume I'm setting up the test incorrectly?  Any help would be appreciated.  I've been attempting to follow the Angular documentation on testing.  If this would be helpful, this is how the beginning of my AuthService looks:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AdalService } from 'ng2-adal/core';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    public authType: string = null;
    public connection: string = null;
    public accessToken: string = null;
    public refreshToken: string = null;

    constructor(private adalService: AdalService, private http: Http) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by editing the karma.conf.js file and adding to the files:[]

```
{ pattern: 'node_modules/ng2-adal/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
{ pattern: 'node_modules/ng2-adal/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },
{ pattern: 'node_modules/adal-angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
{ pattern: 'node_modules/adal-angular/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },
```